# Firebase Auth for multiple websites

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

For Firebase local it states "An explicit sign out is needed to clear that state. Note that Firebase Auth web sessions are single host origin and will be persisted for a single domain only."

Is there any way for logins to be persisted for multiple domains with one login?

Comment: That is not currently supported. You would have to build your own mechanism for that. Do you need this for multiple subdomains?

Comment: For subdomains and domains. Could utilizing cookies work?

Comment: Cookies will not work for cross domain persistence. For cross domain persistence, you typically need to use a cross origin iframe.